# performance bottleneck with httpclient in c#

Tags: c#, httpclient

we've web services written with MVC web API which deployed on our web server and our client from all over the country connect to this server and call our apis via internet and of course intranet (for client who are inside the organization).

sometimes the **response time of requests** becomes **tremendously low** every single request takes about **20 second** (even though they're very lightweight) to be completely replied from server and deliver response to the user **(which in normal condition takes less than 1 second)**, do notice that we have web client as well and exactly in the times that our windows client requests become so low and problematic our web site works perfectly and with highest possible performance.

In fact the services that clients connect to are the same in other word server for all the clients is the same but the way that client connect to it is slightly different(even thought we have one single generic CallService function in each client). In web application client (which works correctly) ajax and angular http are used but in windows client we use **httpclient**
my guess is that there is some kind of bottleneck with **httpclient** which affect the performance too much but we don't know what
here is our CallService Code

```
 public static T CallService<T>(Object obj, string url, string request,string errorMsg="")
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(frmsetting.Frmsetting.setting.ServiceIP);// "http://172.16.3.249/"
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        if (frmsetting.Frmsetting.setting.userSession !=null)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", frmsetting.Frmsetting.setting.userSession.SessionKey);
        url = "archiveApi/" + url;
        HttpResponseMessage response=null;
        try
        {
            switch (request.ToLower())
            {
                case "post": response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, obj).Result; break;
                case "put": response = client.PutAsJsonAsync(url, obj).Result; break;
                case "get": response = client.GetAsync(url).Result; break;
                case "delete": response = client.DeleteAsync(url).Result; break;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            if(e.Message== "One or more errors occurred.")
                throw new Exception("سرور در دسترس نیست.لطفا اتصال شبکه و در دسترس بودن سایت را چک کنید"+ Environment.NewLine + client.BaseAddress);
        }
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, (typeof(T)));
        else
        {
            string text = null;
            var stream1 = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream1).Replace("AT+CSCS=","");
            if (errorMsg != "") errorMsg += "$$";
            errorMsg +=Environment.NewLine+response.StatusCode.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +text /*response.ReasonPhrase.ToString()*/;
            throw new Exception(errorMsg);
        }
    }
```

we're pulling our hair over this issue and situation is terrible

any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't running in the 2 concurrent connections per domain limit?

Comment: HTTP 1.1 itself has a recommendation that a client can make only two concurrent connections to each domain/server. This limit isn't suitable for modern servers and can be overriden by changing [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) directly or through configuration

Comment: You should reuse such instance if possible or at least dispose them after using. As you keep creating new ones, such instance will exhaust native networking resources (like port/buffer and so on).